# Refresh Captcha image with jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, captcha

I have an `HTML` image tag on a razor page. This image shows a generated captcha. I added some jquery to refresh this image when it is clicked. This works on my pc, but as soon as I publish it to a server nothing happens when clicking the image.

```
<img id="captcha-image" src="@Url.Action("Captcha", "Home")" />
...
$("#captcha-image").click(function () {
    this.src = "@Url.Action("Captcha", "Home")";
});
```

**EDIT:**
I've determined that this happens because the image is probably cached by the browser. Now I want to send a random number in the GET request so that browser caching does not negate my efforts.

The problem now is how to get the random number in the appropriate place:

```
$("#captcha-image").click(function () {
    this.src = "@Url.Action("Captcha", "Home", new { r = System.Random.Next() })";
});
```

This will not work because `Next()` is not a static method in `System.Random` and I need an `Random` object to reference in order to use it.

I also tried using the JavaScript random method:

```
$("#captcha-image").click(function () {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random());
    this.src = "@Url.Action("Captcha", "Home", new { r = randomNumber})";
});
```

The problem here is the variable `randomNumber` is not visible in the scope of the c# code-block in the `@Url.Action`.

Comment: Why not just use `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]` on your action method to prevent cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use replace to change the randomNumber string with its value, also change outer double quotes to single and pass randomNumber to anonymous object initializer.

```
this.src = '@Url.Action("Captcha", "Home", new { randomNumber = "_randomNumber_"})'.replace("_randomNumber_", randomNumber );
```

Other way could be concatenating server side code with javascript to make query string

```
this.src = '@Url.Action("Captcha", "Home")?randomNumber' + randomNumber ;
```

Comment: this.src = '@Url.Action("Captcha", "Home")?randomNumber=' + randomNumber;

Answer (score 0):

```
//Put This one Partial view

<img src="@Url.Action("GetCaptchaImage", "Vulpith_Public",new { dt=@DateTime.Now},Request.Url.Scheme)" />
```

```
     //And call ajax from this partial view as following

function Captcharefresh() {
$.ajax({
             url: "../Vulpith_Public/_GetCaptcha",
             type: "post",
             dataType: "html",
             data: {},
success: function (data) {
    $('#codeRefresh').html(data)
},
error: function (data) {
}
});
}


//and create actions as following

public FileResult GetCaptchaImage(DateTime dt)
{
    CaptchaRandomImage CI = new CaptchaRandomImage();
    this.Session["CaptchaImageText"] = CI.GetRandomString(5); // here 5 means I want to get 5 char long captcha
    //CI.GenerateImage(this.Session["CaptchaImageText"].ToString(), 300, 75);
    // Or We can use another one for get custom color Captcha Image 
    CI.GenerateImage(this.Session["CaptchaImageText"].ToString(), 300, 75, Color.DarkGray, Color.White);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    CI.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/png");
}


//One more action as
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _GetCaptcha()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```